# How can I properly target android tv with Codename One?

Tags: codenameone, android-tv

As stated in the title, I would like to know if Codenameone allows the creation of Android Tv specifics applications.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: no.

Longer answer: it shouldn't be too hard but we didn't see any demand for TV or Android Wear for that matter.

The code itself should work just fine on TV since it handles focus behavior and physical keys correctly. It derives from LWUIT code which was optimized for TV's in the day and is in fact the basis for a DTV standard.

In theory you can just use [include source](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html) and try to update the project settings to support TV. I don't think it would be hard but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: It could be very interesting to be able to develop apps for smart TVs with Codename One :)

Comment: It would be interesting to develop for smartwatches too & cars. All of those targets are possible. In fact there is a fork of Codename One that is used in the auto industry. The problem is the business case. Will doing this bring us more users or focusing on improving mobile. So far it seems the latter is far more important especially to the enterprise crowd.